# What can be the cause for helm error "TILLER: unexpected EOF"

Tags: kubernetes, eof, kubernetes-helm

we execute in our automated pipelines this command:

```
helm list --namespace foobar
```

We experience rarely that error:

```
Error: Get https://172.21.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps?labelSelector=OWNER%!D(MISSING)TILLER: unexpected EOF
```

The next run is working fine. in between we didn't change any thing.

So we wonder, what the reason could be. Issue we found, which are more or less similar does not explain it, at least as far we understand them. As it seems to be a random error.

We found these issues:

- helm still ignores kubeconfig #2520 - https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2520
- Error: Get `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps?labelSelector=OWNER%!D(MISSING)TILLER:` dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused #4020 - https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/4020
- Connection refused error when issuing helm install command #3460 - https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3460
- Helm list Error: Get `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps?labelSelector=OWNER%!D(MISSING)TILLER:` dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused #3870 - https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3870
- Tiller pods can't connect to k8s apiserver #2464 - https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2464

Comment: Have you checked `Tiller` Pod for any other relevant events: `kubectl logs <tiller-Pod-name> -n kube-system`?

Comment: Functionally not. I will do this next time.